# Are zero length timers still necessary in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am finally getting around to really implementing some jQuery solutions for my apps (which is seeming to also involve a crash course in javascript).

In studying examples of plugins, I ran across this code. I'm assuming the author created the zero length timer to create some seperation of the running code, so that the init functon would finish quickly.

```
function hovertipInit() {

  var hovertipConfig = {'attribute':'hovertip',
                        'showDelay': 300,
                        'hideDelay': 700};

  var hovertipSelect = 'div.hovertip';


  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(hovertipSelect).hovertipActivate(hovertipConfig,
                                       targetSelectById,
                                       hovertipPrepare,
                                       hovertipTargetPrepare);
  }, 0);

}
```

Is needing this type of seperation common? 
Is creating the zero length timer still the best way to handle this situation, or is there a better to to handle this in jQuery?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: I don't think it's going to be possible to give a really accurate answer to this question without knowing the context in which hovertipInit is called. The author is trying to make this run after something. What?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this article](http://blog.thinkature.com/index.php/2006/11/26/escaping-the-javascript-call-stack-with-settimeout/) that explains when this is necessary.

Also check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282499/what-is-settimeoutfunction-dostuff-0-actually-supposed-to-do).

It is not very common, but is necessary when you need to escape the call stack of an event.